# Parsing - JSON - Array of Arrays

Tags: php, javascript, json

A JSON array has the form:

```
[[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c]]
```

Is there a better way than split?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is most certainly *not* the best way to parse JSON. JSON parsers exist for a reason. **Use them.**

In JavaScript, use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var input = '[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]';
var arrayOfArrays = JSON.parse(input);
```

In PHP, use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$input = '[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]';
$arrayOfArrays = json_decode($input);
```

Comment: @stack.user.0—JASON.parse was introduced in ES5, there are still a good number of older browsers around that do not support it so you still need a JSON library to fill the gaps.

Comment: You might want to re-read the RFC (linked in my answer). From section 2: "A JSON text is a serialized object or array." And section 8 gives a clear example of a JSON array.

Comment: @jsumners thanks, I stand corrected. Always thought the top-level element had to be an object. Thank you for clearing that up for me! I feel like an idiot.

Comment: @MAt Thank you , I returned json array of arrays from code behind and at javascript i used JSON.parse for parsing array of arrays json object into a set of arrays

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use regular expressions. As has been mentioned, you must first have [valid JSON](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) to parse. Then it is a matter of using the tools already available to you.

So, given the valid JSON string `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, we can write the following PHP:

```
$json = "[[1,2],[3,4]]";
$ar = json_decode($json);
print_r($ar);
```

Which results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

If you want to decode it in JavaScript, you have a couple options. First, if your environment is new enough (e.g. [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json#Native_encoding_and_decoding_in_browsers)), then you can use the native `JSON.parse` function. If not, then you should use a library like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to parse the JSON.

Assuming `JSON.parse` is available to you:

```
var inputJSON = "[[1,2],[3,4]]",
    parsedJSON = JSON.parse(inputJSON);

alert(parsedJSON[0][0]); // 1
```

Comment: i believe `json_decode($json);` without the second parameter `TRUE` will return objects. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Uh, I wrote the PHP and ran it through the interpreter before posting. The second parameter set to true would turn `{"foo":"bar"}` into an associative array instead of an actual object. I didn't pass an object to the decoder. I passed an array.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript , I think you can use `Eval()` →　`eval()` method...

Comment: No, no no no no... [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Yes , I know that .  I just said one way to implement it.  Before Json.parse appeared , I always use it in my old project . :)

Comment: Well, there are better, safer ways of doing it now. Also, it's `eval`, not `Eval` (case matters).

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: I know it's a gap filler for deficient browsers, but at the heart of Douglas Crockford's json2.js JSON.parse method is an eval. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js